# ArangoDB- duplicate edges

Tags: arangodb, pyarango

I am using pyArango to create edges between two documents using the function

```
Graph.createEdge()
```

The problem I am facing is that ArangoDB allows to create duplicate edges with the same _to, _from pair. How to avoid this situation in ArangoDB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy solution is to check before insertion using **fetchFirstExample()** on the edges collection:

```
try :
  edge = myEdgesCollection.fetchFirstExample({"_to": doc2._id, "_from": doc1._id})[0]
except :
  edge = myGraph("myEdgesCollection", doc1, doc2, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible via some constraint role,

You can avoid it at the insert level:

When creating an edge, use the next query:

```
UPSERT {_from : @from, _to : @to}
INSERT {_from : @from, _to : @to, label : "knows"} 
UPDATE {} IN @@edgeCollection
```

If there's a match it won't create it (**but notice, it will update it** so leave the update object empty )